# Code breaks with error: $$slots is an illegal variable name

Tags: svelte

I want to make an optional slot for my component, followed the instruction from the [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/optional-slots) down to my local machine in VS Code, but it's not working and the view are not showing.

Can't find any resources & fixes from the net, how can I fix this?

`Stacktrace`

```
[0] rollup v2.26.4
[0] bundles src/main.js → public\build\bundle.js...
[0] [!] (plugin svelte) ValidationError: $$slots is an illegal variable name
[0] src\views\Settings\SettingsItem.svelte
[0] 16:   </div>
[0] 17:
[0] 18:   {#if $$slots.trailing}
[0]            ^
[0] 19:     <slot name="trailing" />
[0] 20:   {:else}
[0] ValidationError: $$slots is an illegal variable name
[0]     at error (C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\utils\error.ts:25:16)
[0]     at Component.error (C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\Component.ts:406:3)
[0]     at Component.warn_if_undefined (C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\Component.ts:1300:10)
[0]     at Object.enter (C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\nodes\shared\Expression.ts:114:17)
[0]     at visit (C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\node_modules\estree-walker\src\estree-walker.js:51:10)
[0]     at walk (C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\node_modules\estree-walker\src\estree-walker.js:2:9)
[0]     at new Expression (C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\nodes\shared\Expression.ts:63:3)
[0]     at new IfBlock$1 (C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\nodes\IfBlock.ts:14:21)
[0]     at C:\Users\Fukka\Documents\Electron\maze-player-svelte\node_modules\svelte\src\compiler\compile\nodes\shared\map_children.ts:53:16
[0]     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

`Settings.svelte`

```html
<SettingsItem
  href="/settings"
  title="Music Path"
  subtitle="Choose where we look for music"
/>
```

`SettingsItem.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { link } from "svelte-spa-router";

  export let href;
  export let title = "No title given";
  export let subtitle;
</script>

<a use:link {href} class="settings-item">
  <div class="detail">
    <p class="title">{title}</p>

    {#if subtitle}
      <p class="subtitle">{subtitle}</p>
    {/if}
  </div>

  <!-- HERE -->
  {#if $$slots.trailing}
    <slot name="trailing" />
  {:else}
    <i class="bx bx-chevron-right icon" />
  {/if}
</a>
```

Comment: You don't show an example of using the slot, the example usage of `SettingsItem` doesn't allow for passing in slot contents. So I wonder whether the compiler works that out and knows there's no chance of `$$slots` being usable?

Comment: @Fukka What `svelte` version are you using?

Comment: @ianmjones I thought `slot` here works similar to vue's `slot`... I didn't show it because I don't need it to be filled (yet) but later on the other items. And I think that's how slot should work. am I wrong?

Comment: @juliomalves version `3.24.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be one version behind. [`$$slots` was introduced in version `3.25.0`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3250).

Upgrading `svelte` to >= `3.25.0` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those who can't update svelte to the specified version in @juliomalves's answer for some reason, placing the `<i>` tag inside the slot works perfectly.

`SettingsItem.svelte`

```html
<div class="settings-item" on:click>
  <div class="detail">
    <p class="title">{title}</p>

    {#if subtitle}
      <p class="subtitle">{subtitle}</p>
    {/if}
  </div>

  <slot name="trailing">
    <i class="bx bx-chevron-right icon" />
  </slot>
</div>
```

`Settings.svelte`

```html
<SettingsItem
  title="Music Path"
  subtitle="Choose where we look for music"
  on:click={toggleModal}
>
  <p slot="trailing">some neat text in the slot</p>
</SettingsItem>

<SettingsItem
  title="Metadata"
  subtitle="Automatically retrieve and update missing album art and metadata (requires internet)"
/>
```